# Verilog Random Number Generator

Tags: numbers, verilog, generator

```
module random_num_gen(
  input  clk,
  input  rst_n,
  output [1:0] data
);

wire feedback = data[1] ^ data[0] ;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)

if (~rst_n) 
data <= 4'hf;
else
data <= {data[1:0], feedback} ;
endmodule
```

Hi, I'm new with Verilog and trying to implement a 2 bit random number generator, I'm not too sure where to start but this is what I have implemented so far. Could anyone share any thoughts?

Comment: `output [1:0] data` should be `output reg [1:0] data` since `data` is assigned in an always block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for thoughts and not a correction to the code (which doesn't generate a random number - point 4), I have a few points:

**1)** data is a 2 bit output port. Yet after reset, you are setting it

```
data<= 4'hf; // 4 bits
```

This should be changed to **2'b11**

**2)** As Greg said, you should change your output port to

```
output reg [1:0] data
```

As you are doing a procedural assignment to data, it has to be a reg and not a wire.

**3)** You should understand that with the following code:

```
data <= {data[1:0], feedback} ;
```

You are essentially assigning a 3-bit signal to a 2-bit register. In this case, the MSB of your signal (ie data[1]) will be truncated. 
You could essentially change this to

```
data <= {data[0], feedback} ;
```

and you would have the same functionality.

**4)** I created a working example of your code: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3YgQ

Looking at the simulation results, you can see that your code doesn't actually generate a random 2-bit number, but rather follows a clear pattern. Your formula won't work for a 2-bit number. You can figure out why as a thought experiment.